# Keep track of pagination and go back most recent last page number in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on an ecommerce, where I am using material UI pagination component for implementing pagination. Here is new requirement arises. I need to add functionality in pagination: if user click on let's say respectively 3,7,11,13 if they click on browser back button they will go back to 11 then 7 then 3 and lastly 1. How do I do that?

I am using react, react router dom.

Here is pagination structure:

[image: Pagination structure]

FYI, this is url and API structure:
[URL and API structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2mfO.png)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductList from "../../components/common/ProductList/ProductList";
import {
  GET_PRODUCTS_BY_BRAND,
  GET_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY,
  GET_PRODUCTS_BY_SUBCATEGORY,
  GET_PRODUCTS_BY_VENDOR,
} from "../../requests/HomePageApi";
import { Pagination } from "@material-ui/lab";
import "./ShopPage.scss";

const ShopPage = () => {
  const { type, slug, subcategory } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  // const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [brands, setBrands] = useState([]);
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);
  const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([]);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);
  const [limit, setLimit] = React.useState(60);
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(60);
  const [sideFilter, setSideFilter] = useState(false);
  const [vandor, setvandor] = useState({
    vendorImg: "",
    vendorName: "",
    vendorSlug: "",
  });

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    // brands: "",
    color: "",
    size: "",
    price: "",
  });

  const closeSideFilter = () => {
    setSideFilter(false);
  };

  const getProducts = async (slug, qParams) => {
    try {
      let res;

      if (type === "category") {
        subcategory
          ? (res = await GET_PRODUCTS_BY_SUBCATEGORY(
              slug,
              subcategory,
              qParams
            ))
          : (res = await GET_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY(slug, qParams));
      }

      if (type === "brand") res = await GET_PRODUCTS_BY_BRAND(slug, qParams);
      if (type === "store") res = await GET_PRODUCTS_BY_VENDOR(slug, qParams);

      if (res) setLoading(false);

      if (res && res.products && res.products.length > 0) {
        setProducts(res.products);
        setFilteredProducts(res.products);
        setTotal(res.total);
        setCount(Math.ceil(res.total / limit));

        if (type === "brand") {
          setvandor({
            vendorImg: `/assets/images/brand/${res.products[0].brand_logo}`,
            vendorName: res.products[0].brand_name,
            vendorSlug: res.products[0].brand_slug,
          });
        } else if (type === "store") {
          setvandor({
            vendorImg: `/assets/images/brand/${res.products[0].brand_logo}`,
            vendorName: res.products[0].shop_name,
            vendorSlug: res.products[0].vendorSlug,
          });
        }

        if (res.colors) {
          const uniqueColors = [...new Set(res.colors)];
          setColors(uniqueColors);
        }

        if (res.sizes) {
          const uniqueSizes = [...new Set(res.sizes)];
          setSizes(uniqueSizes);
        }

        // if (res.brands) setBrands(res.brands);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // console.log({ filteredProducts, filter, page, count, limit, total });

  React.useMemo(() => {
    let qParams = {
      page: page,
      limit: limit,
      size: filter.size,
      color: filter.color,
      // brands: filter.brands,
      price: filter.price.length ? `${filter.price[0]},${filter.price[1]}` : "",
    };

    if (slug) {
      getProducts(slug, qParams);
    }
  }, [slug, page, limit, filter, count]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPage(0);
  }, [filter]);

  const changeLimit = (limit) => {
    setPage(0);
    setLimit(limit);
  };

  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    // window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
    setPage(value - 1);
  };

  const slugTitle = (slug) => slug.split("-").join(" ");


  return (
    <FadeTransition>
      {/* {loading && (
        <div className="section-big-py-space ratio_asos py-5">
          <div className="custom-container">
            <Skeleton type="ShopPage" />
          </div>
        </div>
      )} */}

      {!loading && products === null && (
        <div className="section-big-py-space ratio_asos py-5">
          <div className="custom-container">
            <h3 style={{ color: "#32375A", textAlign: "center" }}>
              Sorry, No Product Found!
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      {products && (
        <div className="title-slug-section">
          <h2 class="title-slug">{slug && slugTitle(slug)}</h2>
        </div>
      )}

      {products && (
        <section className="section-big-py-space ratio_asos">
          {/* {type !== "category" && (
            <div className="merchant-page-header">
              <div className="custom-container">
                <div
                  className="shadow-sm bg-white rounded p-3 mb-5 d-flex align-items-center w-100"
                  style={{ minHeight: "132px" }}
                >
                  <div className="row align-items-center w-100">
                    <div className="col-lg-6">
                      <div className="row align-items-center">
                        {vandor && vandor.vendorImg && (
                          <div className="col-auto">
                            <Image
                              src={vandor.vendorImg}
                              alt={vandor.vendorName}
                              className="img-fluid merchant-img"
                            />
                          </div>
                        )}
                        <div className="col-auto mt-lg-0 mt-2">
                          <h3 className="mb-0"> {vandor.vendorName} </h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )} */}
          <div className="collection-wrapper">
            <div className="custom-container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-3 collection-filter category-page-side">
                  {/* <SidebarFilter
                    type={type}
                    brands={brands}
                    colors={colors}
                    sizes={sizes}
                    onChange={(data) => setFilter(data)}
                  /> */}

                  <InnerCategory />

                  {products && (
                    <RowSlider title="New Products" products={products} />
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="collection-content col-lg-9">
                  <div className="page-main-content">
                    <div className="collection-product-wrapper">
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xl-12">
                          {/* <Button
                            variant='contained'
                            className='bg-dark text-light d-lg-none mb-3 mt-2 w-100'
                            onClick={() => setSideFilter(true)}
                          >
                            <span className='filter-btn  '>
                              <i
                                className='fa fa-filter'
                                aria-hidden='true'
                              ></i>
                              Filter
                            </span>
                          </Button> */}
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <MainFilter
                        type={type}
                        // brands={brands}
                        colors={colors}
                        sizes={sizes}
                        page={page}
                        limit={limit}
                        onCountChange={(c) => changeLimit(c)}
                        onChange={(data) => setFilter(data)}
                      />

                      {/* <TopFilter
                        onCountChange={(x) => changeLimit(x)}
                        total={total}
                        page={page}
                        limit={limit}
                        setSideFilter={setSideFilter}
                      /> */}

                      {filteredProducts && (
                        <ProductList products={filteredProducts} />
                      )}

                      {count > 1 && (
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4">
                          <Pagination
                            count={count}
                            page={page + 1}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            shape="rounded"
                          />
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      )}

      {!loading && products?.length === 0 && (
        <div className="merchant-page-header">
          <div className="custom-container pt-5">
            <div
              className="shadow-sm bg-white rounded p-3 mb-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-100"
              style={{ minHeight: "132px" }}
            >
              <h3 className="mb-0">No Products found!</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      <Drawer
        open={sideFilter}
        className="add-to-cart"
        onClose={() => setSideFilter(false)}
        transitionDuration={400}
        style={{ paddingLeft: "15px" }}
      >
        <SidebarFilter
          onClose={closeSideFilter}
          type={type}
          // brands={brands}
          colors={colors}
          sizes={sizes}
          onChange={(data) => setFilter(data)}
        />
      </Drawer>
    </FadeTransition>
  );
};

export default ShopPage;
```

Comment: You could make the current page part of the URL. A queryString parameter would be my suggestion. What have you tried though? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use react-router-dom to implement pagination in this way you will get benefit of  browser history and when you will click on browser back button it will open most recent page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would like to have URL to represent selected page, so you could refresh the page and still be on the same page. Or share the exact page via copy-paste of URL. Especially on e-commerce sites. So I would recommend to sync selected page with URL.

While it's so common scenario, i have couple hooks for that. First of all - URL hook, which should work with your reactjs app setup.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hook-use-url

and then couple more hooks to not worry about pagination details inside component:

`usePage.js`:

```js
import useUrl from "hook-use-url";

export default function usePage() {
  const url = useUrl();

  const page = url.get({ variable: "page" })
    ? parseInt(url.get({ variable: "page" }), 10)
    : 1;

  const setPage = (value) => {
    url.multipleActions({
      setPairs: [{ variable: "page", value: value }],
    });
  };

  return [page, setPage];
}
```

and `usePerPage.js`:

```js
import useUrl from "hook-use-url";

export default function usePerPage() {
  const url = useUrl();

  const perPage = url.get({ variable: "per-page" })
    ? parseInt(url.get({ variable: "per-page" }), 10)
    : 25;

  const setPerPage = (value) => {
    url.multipleActions({
      setPairs: [
        { variable: "page", value: 1 },
        { variable: "per-page", value },
      ],
    });
  };

  return [perPage, setPerPage];
}
```

Inside components you can use these like so:

(Take a note that which page is 1st depends on your backend API, in my case 1st page is always `1` and not `0`, but mui.com component starts from `0` that's why there is `-1` and `+1`).

```
function MyComp(){
  const [page, setPage] = usePage();
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = usePerPage();
  
// ....

return (
  <TablePagination
    count={totalRows}
    page={page - 1} 
    onPageChange={(e, newPage) => {
      setPage(newPage + 1);
    }}
    rowsPerPage={perPage}
    onRowsPerPageChange={(e) => {
      setPerPage(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
)

}
```

Comment: I added url and pagination structure. Is this possible the way it's structure now.

Comment: you save pagination in active state, so if component is unmounted (e.g. during page refresh), pagination data is gone. My sample saves pagination data into URL. So you need to change anything about url to be saved in react state hook but i would recommend to remove what you have instead and use url-based pagination.

Comment: also browser's history API is auto connected to URL changes, if you do all pagination in state, you need to sync that with history api too, to keep history steps so browser would be able to walk through history with "back" button. Of course you can even code custom history api, keep track of what pages visited etc. etc.